# Issue using progress_recorder (celery-progress): extends time of task

Tags: python, django, progress-bar, django-celery

I want to use celery-progress to display progress bar when downloading csv files

my task loop over list of cvs files, open each files, filtered data and produce a zip folder with csv filtered files (see code below)

but depending where set_progress is called, task will take much more time

if I count (and set_progress) for files processed, it is quite fast even for files with 100000 records

but if I count for records in files, that would be more informative for user, it extends time by 20

I do not understand why

how can I manage this issue

```
for file in listOfFiles:
    
    # 1 - count for files processed
    i += 1
    progress_recorder.set_progress(i,numberOfFilesToProcess, description='Export in progess...')

    records = []

    with open(import_path + file, newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        csv_headings = ','.join(next(spamreader))
        for row in spamreader:
            # 2 - count for records in each files processed (files with 100000 records)    
            # i += 1
            # progress_recorder.set_progress(i,100000, description='Export in progess...')                 
            site = [row[0][positions[0]:positions[1]]]
            filtered_site = filter(lambda x: filter_records(x,sites),site)
            for site in filtered_site:
                records.append(','.join(row))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a very high number of records then likely there's no need to update the progress on every one, and the overhead of updating the progress in the backend every time could become substantial. Instead you could do something like this in the inner loop:

```
if i % 100 == 0:
    # update progress for every 100th entry
    progress_recorder.set_progress(i,numberOfFilesToProcess, description='Export in progress...')
```